# Prove that V is finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I just started on Hilbert spaces and found the following exercise:

> Let $V$ be a vector space with inner product that has a complete and finite orthonormal set $\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$. Show that $V$ is finite dimensional

Here what came to my mind: I know that every vector space with finite dimension with an inner product has an orthonormal base, but is the reciprocal true? if it is, then i just have to show that the given orthonormal set is a base?

Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think a complete set means it spans the whole space, so you just need to show that the $x_i$ are linearly independent

Comment: How is a *complete orthonormal set* defined?